# Contribution updating the wrong members record

Tags: wordpress, civimember, contributions

We have CiviCRM 4.7.12 working on Wordpress 4.6.1. having no problems other than described below.

For a few months now, we've noticed that occasionally when an existing member renews using PayPal, their contribution record correctly records their contribution (usually twice!), but their membership record is not being updated.  Instead, another contact's expired membership record is being updated to show a new membership, without a contribution.  When the confirmation receipt is sent to the contact who has made the contribution, it shows the membership new start and end dates of the other contact.  We have to do manual changes to both contacts records to put things right.

We have had no contributions off-line for a while to test whether this problem only affects PayPal users.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so how did you correct things please?  I'm totally baffled as to why this is happening.  I've delayed reporting this for a while because I was hoping that things would correct themselves following 2 or 3 upgrades.

This is a bit similar to 
[Membership creation is altering unrelated records](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15265/membership-creation-is-altering-unrelated-records) but there has been no answer to that question.

Comment: Anything odd about your Unsupervised Matching Rules?

Comment: Do both the contact shares the same email ID - by any chance

Comment: Ramesh - No they don't share the same email ID.  But the contact making the contribution did use a new email address through PayPal that wasn't currently on the system.  Both the contributor and the contact whose membership was updated, share hotmail.com and hotmail.co.uk addresses.

Comment: peterdnz - Can't spot anything odd.  This reserved rule is pre-configured with matching fields to optimize dedupe scanning performance. It matches on:    Email only

Answer (score 1):

It seems this problem has been reported as a bug at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19594 "Wrong membership Updated"